# Where can I find an audio recording of Ethics of the Fathers 1:14 read in Hebrew?

Tags: product-recommendation, hebrew, pirke-avot-ethicsof

Where can I find an audio recording of [Ethics of the Fathers 1:14](http://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1.14?lang=bi) read in Hebrew (closer to the form of Hebrew it was written in and not in Modern Hebrew, if possible)?

PS: As am sure you can tell, I don't speak Hebrew. I came upon the mishna in Erich Fromm's *The Fear of Freedom* and the meaning resonated with me and I became interested in hearing it in the original. Thank you.

PS 2: I originally asked this question in the V'dibarta Bam chat room on this site.

Comment: Welcome to *Mi Yodeya*. There are numerous questions on this site related to *Pirkei Avot* ("Ethics of the fathers".) You can use the search feature to find them. Regarding "closer to the form of Hebrew it was written in and not in Modern Hebrew,", someone pronouncing these words in an audio would be pronouncing them in their "original" form adding in of course, whatever accent he may have. In that sense, there is no "Modern Hebrew". Since you said that you don't understand Hebrew (did I get this right), I am confused as to what you seek when you stated this. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

There is popular song by Mordechai Ben David in which the lyrics are this mishnah from Pirkei Avot. You can hear the song [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QjkX2HJB-bA).

Here is the mishnah (Pirkei Avot 1:14) transliterated into English.

> :הוא היא אומר, אם אין אני לי, מי לי. וכשאני לעצמי מה אני. ואם לא עכשיו, אימתי
>
> Hu haya omer, Im ein ani li, mi li. Uch'she'ani l'atzmi, mah ani. V'im lo achshav, eimotai:

(In the song, the singer pronounces "eimotai" as "eimosai," because he uses Ashkenazi pronunciation. But Hebrew pronunciations are a completely different topic.)

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a lecture](https://torahdownloads.com/player.html?ShiurID=1018014) about that mishna - the mishna is read in Hebrew and translated starting from 10 seconds in.